# What is the use of "user = self.model(useremail=BmUserManager.normalize_email(useremail))" ? is it used to create a new custom user?

Tags: python, django, django-views

```
class BmUserManager(BaseUserManager):

    def create_user(self, useremail, display_name, password=None):
        if not useremail:
            raise ValueError('Users must have an email address')

        user = self.model(useremail=BmUserManager.normalize_email(useremail))
        user.display_name = display_name
        user.email = useremail
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user
```

what is the use of self.model(useremail=BmUserManager.normalize_email(useremail))?

Comment: OK, this is the second question you've posted asking the "use" of a random line of code you've found. This isn't really what SO is for: if you need to know what a line of code does, then run it.

Comment: i know the code how it works..it will create a new custom user..but i want to know deeply how it works Daniel

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `model` attribute of a model manager is just a reference to the model class the manager has been created for. In this case it refers to whatever user model that will use this manager.

Comment: sorry i didnt get it..Can u give some example to understand this concept?

Comment: @AravindAran, The reason behind using `self.model` is that the manager is not tied to a specific user model - it can be attached to any model which has `display_name`, `email`, `useremail` and `set_password` attributes defined.

Comment: ohhh thank u..yeah its superb..so it willl create a new custom user with display_name,email,useremail when if i called like user=BmUser.objects.create_user(display_name,email,useremail) .....is it correct?

Comment: @AravindAran, yes. If you define another model with the same manager, then it will create an instance of that model (providing it has required attributes).

Comment: yeah i have created a another model for custom user like class BmUser(model.Model): ...........so now it create a new instance by using the custom BaseUserManager....is it?

Answer (score 0):

Here **self.model** is refering to the model that you are using (kind of Custom User).And the method inside ***BaseUserManager.normalize_email*** is used to convert the domain of email in lowercase. For Example if you have email like **"Amanmishra1321@GMAil.com"**, then it will convert the email into **"Amanmishra1321@gmail.com"**